# Different display on tkinter button between windows and linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, tkinter, button

I tried to create an interface similar to that of android smartphones.  I had encountered a problem with the white outlines of the buttons of the interface which I had managed to solve with the parameters "highlightthickness=0" and "bd=0".  On windows it worked but once arrived on linux the borders are there and I tried several parameters like "borderwidth=0" in vain.  Does anyone know how to fix this contour problem on linux please?
PS: I've linked the images to make it easier to understand

[linux display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3AGi.png)

[windows display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V28Xw.png)

```
from tkinter import *
import time 
import webbrowser  
import sys        

interface = Tk()

interface.title("SmartFace")

interface.geometry("325x600")  
interface.minsize(325, 600)  
interface.maxsize(325, 600)  

wallpaper_image = PhotoImage(file="supreme_wallpaper.png")
background_label = Label(interface, image=wallpaper_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

canvas = Canvas(interface, width=400, height=50, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
canvas.pack(side=BOTTOM)
navbar_img = PhotoImage(file="navbar.png")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=navbar_img) 

label = Label(interface, font=("JetBrains Mono", 30, "bold"), bg="#111111", fg="white", bd=8)
label.place(x=90, y=30)


def digitalclock():
    text_input = time.strftime("%H:%M")
    label.config(text=text_input)
    label.after(200, digitalclock)


digitalclock()


def google():
    webbrowser.open_new("google.com")


def twitter():
    webbrowser.open_new("twitter.com")


def spotify():
    webbrowser.open_new("spotify.com")


def amazon():
    webbrowser.open_new("amazon.fr")


def netflix():
    webbrowser.open_new("netflix.fr")


def youtube():
    webbrowser.open_new("youtube.fr")


def off():
    sys.exit()


icon_twitter = PhotoImage(file="icons/icon_twitter.png")
icon_spotify = PhotoImage(file="icons/icon_spotify.png")
icon_youtube = PhotoImage(file="icons/icon_youtube.png")
icon_amazon = PhotoImage(file="icons/icon_amazon.png")
icon_google = PhotoImage(file="icons/icon_google.png")
icon_netflix = PhotoImage(file="icons/icon_netflix.png")
icon_morpion = PhotoImage(file="icons/icon_morpion.png")
icon_mario = PhotoImage(file="icons/icon_mario.png")
icon_navbar_off = PhotoImage(file="navbar_off_button.png")

button_twitter = Button(image=icon_twitter, command=twitter, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
button_spotify = Button(image=icon_spotify, command=spotify, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
button_youtube = Button(image=icon_youtube, command=youtube, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
button_amazon = Button(image=icon_amazon, command=amazon, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
button_google = Button(image=icon_google, command=google, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
button_netflix = Button(image=icon_netflix, command=netflix, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
bouton_morpion = Button(image=icon_morpion, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
button_mario = Button(image=icon_mario, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
button_off = Button(image=icon_navbar_off, command=off, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)

button_google.place(x=45, y=450)
button_youtube.place(x=140, y=450)
button_amazon.place(x=230, y=450)

button_twitter.place(x=45, y=380)
button_netflix.place(x=140, y=380)
button_spotify.place(x=230, y=380)

bouton_morpion.place(x=230, y=310)
button_mario.place(x=45, y=310)

button_off.place(x=130, y=550)

interface.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When I used a 64x64 image with your code I saw the same thing.  A white border around the off button.  I tried the obvious options and none worked.  What did work for me is to chop off a couple of pixels by specifying a slightly smaller width and height:

```
button_off = Button(image=icon_navbar_off, command=off, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, width=62, height=62)
```